# stop chakra from giving a 404 when i have a fallbacksrc

Tags: sentry, chakra-ui

Basically the title.

I have a fallbackSrc so i don't know why this is happening

```
<Img
alt="Profile"
src={session.user.image as string}
width={30}
height={30}
borderRadius={'12'}
fallbackSrc='fallback-icon-1400x1400.png'
/>
```